# Android - Crashlytics - How to upload only one app

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have a Project with a library module and 3 app modules in it. All apps are connected to Crashlytics. Every time I want to distribute a new version of one of the apps it uploads all of them. I use this command to upload the app

```
gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

Is there a way to only upload one app?
Thx in advance for your help. Cheers.

Comment: where do you write this command ?

Comment: I write the command in the Android Studio Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do this. If you have for example two Android App Modules in your project called "app1" and "app2" you can release a specific app using this command:

```
gradlew :app1:assembleRelease :app1:crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use "Upload file..." button to upload single .apk file in Crashlytics plugin for Android Studio.

[image: uploading_screenshot]